# Can access codes be created with the Eventbrite API, like discount codes?

Tags: eventbrite

I've been able to create discount codes using discount_new, is it possible to create access codes with the API too?

I don't see a method on http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/#methods for doing that and discount_new doesn't seem to support it.

I'd like to create customized access codes that allow people to sign up for hidden tickets, such as a volunteer ticket, for example.

Comment: To get help on this website, you need to post code that you've tried  to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now get, create, and update access codes using the following api endpoints:

```
event_list_access_codes
access_code_new
access_code_update
```

Documentation to follow soon, but usage is similar to that for discount codes.  In order to create a new access_code, the corresponding ticket needs to be hidden.  If the "tickets" parameter is not specified, the access code will apply to all tickets (and they all need to be hidden).